# How to pass format to to_timestamp in postgresql?

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have utc epocha in millisecond and I would like my sql return resulting dates in a specific date format.

This works

```
   SELECT to_timestamp(timestamp / 1000) as date
   FROM data
```

This does not work

```
SELECT to_timestamp(timestamp / 1000, 'YYYY-MM-DD HH:MI:SS') as date
FROM data
```

Could you tell me what is wrong in my script and how to fix it please? Thanks

Comment: What's '2019-11-27 14:45' / 1000?

Comment: timestamp is in microseconds so I need to convert it to milliseconds

Comment: It's much better to store timestamps as `timestamp`. https://blog.sql-workbench.eu/post/epoch-mania/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`to_timestamp()` does not format your output. The version where `to_timestamp()` accepts a format mask is used to convert a string value to a proper timestamp.

You need to format the *result* of your conversion (which is a proper timestamp) using `to_char()`.

```
to_char(to_timestamp(timestamp / 1000), 'yyyy-mm-dd hh24:mi:ss') as date
```